# How can I serialize val element in Json

Tags: json, scala, scala-2.10

When serializing the following case class, the val element is not included. Why is that, and can I have it included?

```
case class Asset(id: Option[Int], description: Option[String]= None) {
  val url = "images/" + id.toString+".png"
}
```

**Update: Added Json library, and specification/intended use of the url "property".**

I am using the Json library shipped with Play 2.1/Scala 2.10.

Actually the url property is meant to be a function which will look up the transformation algorithm according to configuration, for example the image can be available locally, or available from an external host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you sould really specify which json serialization library you are using, it is pretty much guaranteed that just doing the following will work:

```
case class Asset(id: Option[Int], description: Option[String]= None, url = "images/" + id.toString+".png")
```

Given that `url` has a default value anyway, turning it into a parameter won't negatively affect your code (you can still do `Asset(None)` by example, as before). The only downside is that now client code might create an `Asset` instance with a different value for `url`, which might not be what you want.

If that's the case, you'll probably need to create a custom json format for your `Asset` class, but without knowing which serialization library you use I can't help much more in this respect.

---

**UPDATE**:

Ooops, I totally missed the fact that the default value for `url` depends on another parameter (`id`) (thanks to @Kristian Domagala for noticing). Thus my above snippet does not compile. One simple solution is to put `url` in a second parameter list as suggested by @Kristian Domagala:

```
case class Asset(id:Option[Int],description:Option[String]=None)(val url:String = "images/" + id.toString+".png")
```

But this might not be ideal as this changed the equality semantics of `Asset` (`url` is not taken into account anymore when comparing instances), and also changes the construction syntax : when explicitly specifying the `url` value, you'd need to do something like `Asset(Some(123))("gfx/myImage.png")` instead of by example `Asset(Some(123), url="gfx/myImage.png")`.
If you can live with these downsides this is certainly the easiest solution.

Otherwise, there is another work around: we can redefine `Asset.apply` ourselve (by hand):

```
case class AssetImpl( val id: Option[Int], val description: Option[String], val url: Option[String]) {
  override def productPrefix = "Asset"
}
type Asset = AssetImpl
object Asset {
  def apply( id: Option[Int], description: Option[String] = None, url: Option[String] = None ) = {
    new Asset( id, description, url.orElse( id.map( "images/" + _ + ".png") ) )
  }
}
```

As you can see I have turned `url` into an `Option` with a default value of `None` (avoiding the previous compilation error, as it does not depend on `id` anymore) due to , and in `def apply...` I instantiate `Asset` with a default value for `url` (this is where I actually get the value of `id`) of `id.map( "images/" + _ + ".png")`.

The rest is basically just noise to be able to redefine `Asset.apply`: it turns out that in fact you cannot redefine the factory of a case class (you can only add separate overloads). So I renamed the class as `AssetImpl`, added a type alias so that noone notices ( ;-) ), and created my very own object `Asset` where I define the `apply` method (which does not conflict anymore with the auto-generated `apply` method because this one is in the distinct `AssetImpl` object.
I could also simply have turned `Asset` into a standard class (non case class) but then I would have to redefine `equals` and `hashCode` which I find more annoying given that it must be maintained when adding/removing fields to the class.

Comment: That doesn't compile. To refer to `id`, the `url` would need to be declared in a second parameter group. I initially downvoted the answer thinking that the second parameter group wouldn't be picked up by serialisation libraries, but it turns out that Jerkson does in fact serialise it. The full declaration needs to be `case class Asset(id:Option[Int],description:Option[String]=None)(val url:String = "images/" + id.toString+".png")`. Incidently, I don't think the value of `url` will be what is expected, given the implementation of `Option.toString`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I had totally missed the `url`->`id` dependency. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I actually ended up moving the calculation of url outside the Asset class.

I am not sure if it is correct conduct to accept an answer I haven't checked myself.